# Is there any way to iterate 2 item lists in same ansible task. I want to iterate ip and port

Tags: ansible

```
-hosts:all
 Gather_facts: yes
 Tasks:
     - name: connectivity
       Shell: |
             nc -zv  68.78.38.48 {{ item}}
             nc -zv  56.66.76.87 {{ item }}
       With_items:
             - 9100
             - 9200
             - 9300
        register: result
      - debug: msg="host: {{ inventory_hostname }}, result: {{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: Please format your code as a code sample. There is help available when editing if you are unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of addresses and a list of ports, you can use the [product filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) to iterate over the cartesian product of the two lists.

For example, the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - list_of_ips:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 2.2.2.2
        - 3.3.3.3
    - list_of_ports:
        - 9100
        - 9200
        - 9300

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "check {{ item.0 }}:{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_ips|product(list_of_ports)|list }}"
```

Results in the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.1', 9100]) => {
    "msg": "check 1.1.1.1:9100"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.1', 9200]) => {
    "msg": "check 1.1.1.1:9200"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.1', 9300]) => {
    "msg": "check 1.1.1.1:9300"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['2.2.2.2', 9100]) => {
    "msg": "check 2.2.2.2:9100"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['2.2.2.2', 9200]) => {
    "msg": "check 2.2.2.2:9200"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['2.2.2.2', 9300]) => {
    "msg": "check 2.2.2.2:9300"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['3.3.3.3', 9100]) => {
    "msg": "check 3.3.3.3:9100"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['3.3.3.3', 9200]) => {
    "msg": "check 3.3.3.3:9200"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['3.3.3.3', 9300]) => {
    "msg": "check 3.3.3.3:9300"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```